# With Reactive Extensions (RX), is it possible to shift .Buffer time back by 10 seconds?

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5, system.reactive

I am using `Buffer` to collect all events over one minute, and present them into a list:

```
this.GetServiceAvailablityRxStream                  
    .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1))
    .Subscribe(
        serviceAvailableList =>
        {
           ...
        }
```

Currently, it buffers at T=1 min, then T=2 min, etc.

I'm wondering if its possible to shift the buffering back by 10 seconds, e.g. make it buffer at T=10 sec, then T=1 min+10 sec, then T=2 min+10 sec, etc.

***What I have tried***

I have tried all combinations of `.Delay`, `.DelaySubscription`, overloads on `.Buffer`, putting `.Delay` before and after the `.Buffer` command, etc, and nothing seems to work.

I'm wondering if this is even possible in RX?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  The key insight is the fact that time can be represented as an Observable.  So use the overload of `Buffer` that accepts an observable as the boundary signal and pass it your own signal using `Observable.Timer`:

```
var first = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
var remainder = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
var boundaries = Observable.Timer(first, remainder);
source.Buffer(boundaries).Subscribe(...);
```

Comment: I'd forgotten about that overload of Timer! +1

Comment: @JamesWorld indeed, there are too many operator variations to remember them all!

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a stream to define the buffer boundaries you want. Fortunately this is quite easy. The following will define the 10 second initial buffer interval, followed by subsequent one minute intervals:

```
var bufferBoundaries =
    Observable.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
```

Then assuming a source stream of `xs` you can do:

```
var bufferedEvents = xs.Buffer(bufferBoundaries);
```